# How do I resolve a System.Security.SecurityException with custom code in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, securityexception

I've created an assembly and referenced it in my Reporting Services report. I've tested the report locally (works), and I then uploaded the report to a report server (doesn't work).

Here is the error that is thrown by the custom code I've written.

> System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed. at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckNReturnSO(PermissionToken
>   permToken, CodeAccessPermission
>   demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Int32 unrestrictedOverride, Int32
>   create) at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Assert(CodeAccessPermission
>   cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Assert()
>   at [Snipped Method Name] at
>   ReportExprHostImpl.CustomCodeProxy.[Snipped Method Name] The action that failed was:
>   Demand The type of the first
>   permission that failed was:
>   System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission
>   The Zone of the assembly that failed
>   was: MyComputer

This project is something I inherited, and I'm not intimately familiar with it. Although I do have the code (now), so I can at least work with it :)

I believe the code that is failing is this:

```
    Dim fio As System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission = New System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission(Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted)
    fio.Assert()
```

However, this kind of stuff is everywhere too:

```
Private Declare Function CryptHashData Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hhash As Integer, ByVal pbData As String, ByVal dwDataLen As Integer, ByVal dwFlags As Integer) As Integer
```

I can see either of these being things that Reporting Services would not accommodate out of the box.

Comment: This could help you: <http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2003/06/20/57023.aspx>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I was able to solve the issue:

- strongly sign the custom assembly in question
- modify the rssrvpolicy.config file to add permissions for the assembly

  ```
                      <CodeGroup
                          class="UnionCodeGroup"
                          version="1"
                          PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
                          Name="Test"
                          Description="This code group grants the Test code full trust. ">
                          <IMembershipCondition
                                  class="StrongNameMembershipCondition"
                                  version="1"
                                  PublicKeyBlob="0024000004800000940100000602000000240000575341310004000001000100ab4b135615ca6dfd586aa0c5807b3e07fa7a02b3f376c131e0442607de792a346e64710e82c833b42c672680732f16193ba90b2819a77fa22ac6d41559724b9c253358614c270c651fad5afe9a0f8cbd1e5e79f35e0f04cb3e3b020162ac86f633cf0d205263280e3400d1a5b5781bf6bd12f97917dcdde3c8d03ee61ccba2c0"
                              />
                      </CodeGroup>
  ```

Side note: here is a great way to get the public key blob of your assembly
[VS trick for obtaining the public key token and blob of a signed assembly](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2006/09/15/4587.aspx).

Comment: any sample powershell script ps1 to modify rssrvpolicy.config ? thx

Answer (score 18):

```
<system.web>

<trust level="Full"/>

</system.web>
```

try this in web.config

Answer (score 0):

Run your service in administrator mode

Answer (score 0):

```
 <CodeGroup class="FirstMatchCodeGroup" version="1" PermissionSetName="FullTrust">
```

For me, the solution was changing the above line in the `rssrvpolicy.config` from `"None"` to `"FullTrust"`.