# Running ASP.NET MVC on Meduim-Trust environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, medium-trust

I am newbie to ASP.NET MVC, I developed a new web application using ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework on .NET 4.5 and it is working just fine.

When trying to deploy onto a shared hosting server, I got an error as the Trust is set to Medium and there is noway to change it to Full.

Even on my local machine if I set Trust to Medium I got same exception:

> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the
>   permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

How could I fix my configuration to allow my application to work on Medium Trust environment. Noticing that my application is not using anything from outside.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

ASP.Net MVC 5 no longer support partial trust for  you need to develop this application in MVC 3 or MVC 4. For more information please read this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25354496/6300200)

Answer (score 0):

You can change configuration of application in web.config file

```
<system.web>
    <securityPolicy>
        <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
    </securityPolicy>
</system.web>
```

Also refer to this if need more details

https://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/62071-SystemSecurityPermissionsSecurityPermission-at-Godaddy-hosting

[How do I resolve a System.Security.SecurityException with custom code in SSRS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428/how-do-i-resolve-a-system-security-securityexception-with-custom-code-in-ssrs)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y.aspx

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555466

Comment: I can't change the Trust value as it is on a shared Hosting Server,  I want to know what I should change in my configuration to make the application work on Medium Trust.
Thanks