# DefaultValue expression for the report parameter ‘UserTokenSIDs’ contains an error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sccm

I have the tried the following posts and still getting the same error.

1. [How do I resolve a System.Security.SecurityException with custom code in SSRS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428/how-do-i-resolve-a-system-security-securityexception-with-custom-code-in-ssrs)
2. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/55fb5871-575d-4646-b092-d0fbc54f746a/error-using-assembly-in-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices
3. https://aristonjavier.wordpress.com/2019/12/23/ax2012-the-defaultvalue-expression-for-the-report-parameter-ax_companyname-contains-an-error/
4. https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/hellodax/posts/error-the-defaultvalue-expression-for-the-report-parameter-ax-companyname-contains-an-error-request-for-the-permission-of-type-system-security-permissions-environmentpermission

When I clicked on any of the SCCM reports, I keep getting the following error. I'm not certain if there is anything in the SCCM that I need to setup/configure.

The DefaultValue expression for the report parameter ‘UserTokenSIDs’ contains an error: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e090' failed. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding  between <system.web> works for me. I found the solution in this thread: https://www.nopcommerce.com/en/boards/topic/4253/request-for-the-permission-of-type-systemsecuritypermissionssecuritypermission-mscorlib-versio

The ReportServer\web.config is the one that I added the trust level to full. Adding to the ReportManager/web.config file did not work.